# Запись значений массива в атрибут val

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть объект. Как записать его значения в атрибут `val` `input`?
Структура объекта такова:

```
Object { Текст: "1", Текст2: "2" }
```

Пишу такой код в инпуте `value="[object Object]"`. Подскажите, как исправить?

```
$.each(map, function(i,e){
    $("#listProduct").val($(e) + ", ");
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас `$(e)` это не значение в объекте, а сам объект. Что бы записать ключь и его значение, использую такое:

```js
$(function() {
  var object = {"Текст": "1", "Текст2": "2"};
  for(var key in object){
    $("#listProduct").val($("#listProduct").val()+key+': '+object[key]+", ")
  };

  // Это что бы убрать запятую в конце
  $("#listProduct").val($("#listProduct").val().replace(/^(.+)\,\ $/, '$1'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="listProduct">
```

Comment: [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)